# onChangeText and setState for nested state don't work with submit

Tags: react-native

For this component I have two nested states.

And I have a text input with a submit button as shown in the code below.

I'd like to save user's input in `this.state.schoolForm.userInput` whenever onChangeText fires, and then save `this.state.schoolForm.userInput` to `this.userInputs.schoolName` when commit button is clicked.

This would work when I just setState to `this.state.userInputValue` (A simple not nested state) However, it wouldn't work when I try to setState to the nested state: `this.state.schoolForm.userInput`

When I click submit button nothing happens but it's supposed to transit to the next state. It seems like the way I save to a nested state is causing the problem but I have followed this post [React setState for nested state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/react-setstate-for-nested-state) and I can't find anything wrong from my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, StatusBar, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';

const states = {
  schoolForm: {
    prompt: "Where did you go to school?",
    userInput: "School name",
  },
  durationForm: {
    prompt: "For how long?",
    userInput: "Duration",
  },
}

export default class NewEducation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //form: states.reviewForm,
      form: states.schoolForm,
      userInputs: {
        schoolName: "",
        duration: ""
      },
      //for testing
      userInputValue: "",
    }
  }

  _nextState = () => {
    switch(this.state.form) {
      case states.schoolForm:
        this.setState({form:states.durationForm});
        break;
      case states.durationForm:
        this.setState({form:states.degreeForm});
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  _submitInfo = () => {
    switch(this.state.form) {
      case states.schoolForm:
        //this.setState({ userInputs: { ...this.state.userInputs, schoolName: this.state.form.userInput} });
        this.setState({ userInputs: { ...this.state.userInputs, schoolName: this.state.userInputValue}});
        break;
      case states.durationForm:
        //this.setState({ userInputs: { ...this.state.userInputs, duration: this.state.form.userInput} });
        this.setState({ userInputs: { ...this.state.userInputs, duration: this.state.userInputValue}});
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    this._nextState();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
        <Text style={styles.textContentWhite}>{this.state.form.prompt}</Text>

        <TextInput
          style={styles.textContentWhite}
          placeholder={this.state.form.userInput}
          placeholderTextColor="#B7BEDE"
          onChangeText={(userInputValue) => 
            //this.setState({ form: {userInput: userInputValue} }
            this.setState({form: { ...this.state.form, userInput: userInputValue }}
              )}
        />

        <Button
          onPress={this._submitInfo}
          title="Submit"
          color="white"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },

  textContentWhite: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

Comment: What do you see when you do `this.setState({form: {...this.state.form, userInput: text}}, () => console.log(this.state.form))`?

Comment: I don't see any errors but after click submit button nothing happens neither

Comment: Nothing gets printed when you `console.log`? Not even `undefined`?

Comment: I suppose the right side screen on expo XDE is displaying the console.log? No there's nothing printed not even undefined.